# Orbiting body constantly spinning while over southern hemisphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm trying to get my bodies to walk around the planet on their own but problems arise when the body gets to the "lower" hemisphere of the planet.
Whenever the body gets there it spins like crazy and won't stop until the body moves back to the "upper" hemisphere of the planet.
**Attractor**

```
public class Attractor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _gravity = -10;

    public void Attract(Body body)
    {
        Vector3 targetDir = (body.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 bodyUp = body.transform.up;

        body.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyUp, targetDir);
        body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(targetDir * _gravity);
    }
}
```

**Body**

```
public class Body : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Attractor _curAttractor;

    private Rigidbody _rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _rb.useGravity = false;
        _rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _curAttractor.Attract(this);
    }
}
```

**PathFollower**

```
public class PathFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float _reach;
    private Path _curPath;
    private Rigidbody _rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void FollowPath(Path p)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        _curPath = p;
        StartCoroutine(FollowCtn());
    }

    private IEnumerator FollowCtn()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Vector3 target;

        while (i < _curPath.Nodes.Length)
        {
            target = PathfindingData.NodeToWorldPosition(_curPath.Nodes[i]);
            Vector3 dir;

            while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target) > _reach)
            {
                dir = target - transform.position;
                dir.Normalize();
                _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + dir * _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                yield return null;
            }

            i++;
        }

        _rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        _curPath = null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this weird behaviour?

Here's what I mean by spins like crazy:
[image: body spins on yaw axis while it is over southern hemisphere]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FromToRotation` is best when you are concerned with where only one axis is pointing because it will alter the directions of the other axes in any way that minimizes the angle between the two rotations. In other words, `FromToRotation` will alter the yaw of your object if doing so reduces the changes needed in pitch or roll.

Because you are concerned with the transform's `up` (always pointing away from the attractor) and `forward` (changing as little as possible between `FixedUpdate` calls), another route is preferable.

Use [`Vector3.OrthoNormalize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.OrthoNormalize.html) and [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to specify the `targetDir` direction as up, and keep the body's `transform.forward` as unchanged as possible (if they are colinear, an arbitrary direction for `forward` is used):

```
Vector3 targetDir = (body.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
Vector3 bodyForward = body.transform.forward; 
Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref targetDir, ref bodyForward); 

body.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(bodyForward, targetDir);     
body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(targetDir * _gravity);
```